# ASP.NET, VB.NET can't insert data into a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I have been troubleshooting this for a week. I try to insert a value into a SQL Server database. It doesn't show any error but when I check the database, there's no data inserted. I might doing something that is wrong here but I can't find it. Thanks for helping.

```
Dim connect As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SqlServer").ToString())

Using coa As New SqlCommand()
    With coa
        .Connection = connect
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    End With

    Try
       connect.Open()

       Dim insertcmd As String

       insertcmd = "insert into tblUserSection (@newValue, @SectionName, @newSectionID) values ," _
       & "@newValue, @SectionName, @newSectionID);"

       coa.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@newValue", SqlDbType.BigInt))
       coa.Parameters("@newValue").Value = newValue

       coa.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SectionName", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
       coa.Parameters("@SectionName").Value = SectionName.ToString

       coa.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@newSectionID", SqlDbType.BigInt))
       coa.Parameters("@newSectionID").Value = newSectionID

       coa.ExecuteNonQuery()
       connect.Close()

       MsgBox("success insert")

    Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("Fail to Save to database")
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: Don't know why you wouldn't see an exception; that query string doesn't look right at all.

Comment: any idea how to write a right query?

Comment: i edit the example from Microsoft page to fit with my codes.

Comment: You are probably inserting the data in one database but then looking for it in another database.

Comment: i already fetch data from other table. i put the alert to print out the value and it really shows the value. the thing is, there is no update in database.

Comment: You can't really use MsgBox in ASP.NET because the message box will appear on the server, not on the client.

Comment: My advise for you (especially if you are troubleshooting this) is to isolate the problem. Create a hardcoded insert statement, withouth any sql parameters. I.e. insert into table select 1,2,3. Then replace 1 with parameter, then 2 as well and so on, so you can isolate the failure.

Answer (score 1):

The insert command is incorrect. It has parameters for both the column names and the value; the parameter names should only be used for the values.

Assuming the column names match the parameter names, here's an updated version of the command.

```
insertcmd = "insert into tblUserSection (newValue, SectionName, newSectionID) values ," _
        & "@newValue, @SectionName, @newSectionID);"
```

The more curious question is why isn't an error showing up. That's because  the insert statement is never getting executed. The ExecuteNonQuery command is run against the connection but insertcmd is never associated with the execution in any way.

I'd recommend creating a SQLCommand and using that to execute the query. Here's a sample (and my code might have mistakes, my vb.net is pretty rusty):

```
Dim sqlcommand as New SqlCommand(coa)
sqlcommand.text = insertcmd
sqlcommand.type = Text
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@newValue", SqlDbType.BigInt))
sqlcommand.Parameters("@newValue").Value = newValue
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SectionName", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
sqlcommand.Parameters("@SectionName").Value = SectionName.ToString
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@newSectionID", SqlDbType.BigInt))
sqlcommand.Parameters("@newSectionID").Value = newSectionID
sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Plus: **after** the `values` keyword, there is an extra erroneous comma, and the opening bracket after the `values` keyword is missing ....

Comment: its similar from what i do. still gettting no luck. everything compiled and runs well. but theres no update in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **CommandText** property of **SqlCommand** after creating the insert command string.
like:

```
Dim connect As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SqlServer").ToString())
    Using coa As New SqlCommand()
        With coa
            .Connection = connect
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        End With
        Try
            connect.Open()
            Dim insertcmd As String
            insertcmd = "insert into [TableName] (newValue, SectionName, newSectionID) values " _
            & "(@newValue, @SectionName, @newSectionID);"
            coa.CommandText = insertcmd
            coa.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@newValue", SqlDbType.BigInt))
            coa.Parameters("@newValue").Value = newValue
            coa.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SectionName", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
            coa.Parameters("@SectionName").Value = SectionName.ToString()
            coa.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@newSectionID", SqlDbType.BigInt))
            coa.Parameters("@newSectionID").Value = newSectionID
            coa.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connect.Close()
            MsgBox("success insert")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Fail to Save to database")
        End Try
    End Using
```

Comment: @IsmaelBinAzman Use this entire code this works fine at my end. I found some problem in your query string.